# CSS sprites - can i do simple math in CSS somehow?

Tags: css, sprite, sprite-sheet

Im using an icon-sheet with all my icons in it, and now referencing them in my CSS.

Each icon is 32*32 and is in a grid like this :

> AA BB CC DD ...
>
> A1 B1 C1 D1 ......
>
> A2 B2 C2 D2 .......
>
> UU XX YY ZZ ......
>
> etc.

Where AA = icon, A1=hover, A2=active.

It works ok, in the CSS right now its like this :

> .icon {
>
> height:32px;
>
> width:32px;
>
> background-image:url('/img/slbuttons.png');
>
> }
>
> .AAicon {background-position:0px 0px;}
>
> .BBicon {background-position:-32px 0px;}
>
> .CCicon {background-position:-64px 0px;}

etc...

What im looking for is somehow to make it abit more simple, the icons doesnt change in size (32*32) so instead of manually writing each of the different icons, i just want to reference that ex. :

AAIcon = x0,y0, BBIcon = x1,y0, CCIcon=x2,y0
A1Icon = x0,y1, etc. etc.

instead of i have to sit and write each 32,64,96,128, etc myself - wasnt it possible to make a (xpos=gridcount*32, ypos=gridcount*32) ?

Reason why i want this is i just changed my icon-pack size and then i have to rewrite ALL those values again, and each block icon/hover/active are actually the same except for the coordinates, would be a big help if i could just have a global varialbe that defines the size and then thats used automatically to adjust the positioning later on.

Dont know if i can that in CSS, maybe thats CSS3 or ?

Im not an expert at all in CSS or WEB development so its probably an easy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure CSS, no you cannot do math. It is strictly a styling language. There are a few options when it comes to dynamically styling your page.

You can use SASS and LESS, which are their own languages, run through a processor (SASS uses Ruby, LESS uses JavaScript) to generate the stylesheet.

The second option would be to use JavaScript, and for a beginner, jQuery would probably be the easiest option. Once you have included the jQuery source using something like `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>` (or alternatively the Google CDN), you are free to utilize the jQuery library in addition to standard JavaScript.

A short snippet to get the height of an image:

```
<script>
var imgHeight = $('.icon').height(); //remove the height and width from your CSS first!
var imgWidth = $('.icon').width();
</script>
```

You can then use jQuery to manipulate the CSS dynamically based on the height of the background image:

```
<script>
var iconA = $('.AAIcon');
iconA.css('background-position','imgHeight');
</script>
```

[jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! By using a css preprocessor you can do math, variables and so much more. The two popular ones are SASS and LESS. SASS is gaining a lot of traction and is what I use. Here is a great rundown of it.

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/88-intro-to-compass-sass/

With a css preprocessor you can do exactly what you are talking about. Good luck! And enjoy easier css!